# If you call funtionA insider funtionB, will functionA be invoked? What is happening in compilation level?

Tags: javascript, function, compilation, invoke

I am reading the "You do not know JS" book series and found am confused by a simple piece of code. In the following code, I tried and nothing will be printed out. foo will not be invoked even there is "foo()" inside function bar. Can any one help me to understand why another foo() wont be invoked during bar?

when the code is compiled, what happend in the line "foo()"? Thanks in advance.

```
function foo() {
  console.log( "5" ); 
}

function bar() {
   var a = 3;
   foo();
}
```

Comment: Does your code call the function `bar()` anywhere? There's no such call in the code you posted. If you don't call `bar()` then nothing will happen.

Comment: bar() is not called anywhere else. Invocation can only happen in global scope? can foo() be invoked inside bar()?

Comment: Yes `foo()` inside the "bar" function is fine. Just put `bar();` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually called the function bar(), you've only defined it.

Comment: In the definition process of bar, does is call foo? foo() seems an invoke

Comment: @Gaoyan yes but to make that happen, somewhere you have to have `bar()`.

Comment: Great, please accept the answer if it is satisfactory.